# Backup file loop in bash

Tags: bash, loops

I'm writing a script that takes a directory, copies all the files from it to a new one, then renames all the files in the new directory to include a -BACKUP in their name before an extension.

so far I have:

```
dir1=$1
dir2=$2

mkdir $dir2
cp -r $dir1/. $dir2

for i in $dir2
do
file=$(basename "$i")
b=${file%.*}
c=${file#"$stub"}
d=-BACKUP
e=$b$d$c
mv $i $e

done
```

Although this only changes the name of the directory, not all the files within the directory.

What am I doing wrong, how would you approach this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get some glob'ing going:

```
for i in "$dir2"/*
```

(Note that this won't catch `.dotfiles`, and will enumerate both files and directories, so you might need a bit more logic if either of these is a problem.)

If you expect that `$dir2` could be empty after the copy, add:

```
shopt -s nullglob
```

before the `for` so that the loop doesn't run at all in that case. (Otherwise you'll get `$dir2/*` literally in `$i` which is undesirable.)

```
mv $i $e
```

won't work, since `$e` doesn't contain a path the way you've built it. Try:

```
mv "$i" "$dir2/$e"
```

(You should quote all those variables if you expect files that contain spaces in their names.)

Comment: For some reason, now my directories are empty.

Comment: Your `mv` command is wrong, should be `mv $i $dir2/$e` - all your files should be in the current directory now...

Comment: I get this error: ``mv: cannot move `testdir' to a subdirectory of itself, `testdir/i-BACKUPi'`` and still the files within the new directory aren't being changed.

Comment: Added a note about running this against an empty directory which could do the sort of thing you're describing - but there would have to be other errors in your substitutions for that name to be generated.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `find` and `rename` on systems that support it:

```
cp -R "$dir1" "$dir2"
find "$dir2" | xargs rename 's/$/-BACKUP/'
```

Comment: FYI -- `rename` is not standard, and different operating systems include different versions of the command with different usage (or, many have no implementation at all).

Comment: Ok, thanks for the heads-up! May not be portable, but it is very practical though =)